# Plotting Year and Month in scatter plot R

Tags: r, dataframe, date, scatter-plot

I have a dataset with Year and Month number that I am trying to plot against another variable, in this case "MEI". Here is a small sample of the data:

```
Year,   Month,  MEI,
1983,   5,  2.556,
1983,   6,  2.167,
1983,   7,  1.741,
1983,   8,  1.13,
1983,   9,  0.428,
1983,   10, 0.002,
1983,   11, -0.176,
1983,   12, -0.176,
1984,   1,  -0.339,
1984,   2,  -0.565,
```

Is there a way to make the x axis continuous over the years (Months-11,12,1,2). I tried:

```
plot(weather$Month, weather$MEI, main = 'Regression for MEI Each Month Over 16.5 Years', 
xlab = 'Month (From May 1983 to December 2008', ylab = 'MEI')
```

and I got this scatter plot.
[image]

Comment: Please [make this question reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) by including example data in a plain text format - for example the output from `dput(yourdata)`. We cannot copy/paste data from images.

Comment: @neilfws It has been updated. I apologize for the poor question presentation.

Comment: There's no strong indication that the x-axis is *not* continuous; the fact that the points are lined up like that seems likely due to the integer nature of the second column (I'm inferring `Month`). (So technically, yes, as integers it is discrete and not continuous ... but that's a property of the data, not something you can just make happen.)

Comment: Are you trying to change the axis labels so that it shows all months, not just the even numbers? Or are you hoping for lines within a year to indicate trends?

Comment: @r2evans Maybe continuous is the wrong word. I am wondering if there is a way to have the months of different years not on the same x value. For example, I would like each value of the x axis to be in order (November 1985, December 1985, January 1986, February 1986, etc.)

Comment: @r2evans I am trying to see if there is a trend over the years. My full dataset is from 1985-2008

Answer (score 1):

One solution is to generate dates from the year/month values by adding "01" as the day. You can do that using `dplyr::mutate`. If you use `ggplot2` for plotting, it will make formatting a date x-axis easier too.

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

weather %>% 
  mutate(Date = as.Date(paste(Year, Month, "01", sep = "-"))) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(Date, MEI)) + 
  geom_point() + 
  scale_x_date(date_labels = "%b %Y")
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You could convert the months and the year to a date and then plot the date against `MEI`:

```
weather$date <- as.Date(paste0(weather$Year, "-", weather$Month, "-01"))

plot(weather$date, weather$MEI, main = 'Regression for MEI Each Month Over 16.5 Years', 
    xlab = 'Month (From May 1983 to December 2008', ylab = 'MEI')
```